# How to increase 100 user cap for OAuth to Google API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-docs-api

My Google project is verified but the user cap displays 100/100.

Google documentation says that OAuth user quotas "might be adjusted for specific apps based on the app history, developer reputation, and riskiness" https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865.

I found the application rate limits page that has a form for increasing the OAuth rate limit quota. https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9028764, https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_quota_increase?sjid=11694072531958001309-EU.

Is it possible to increase the user cap through that form?

Answer (score 1):

Only apps that have **not** been verified and are still in the testing phase have a cap of 100 users.

[image]

If your still seeing the cap then your not verified.

Quota are related to the number of requests that you can make against a given api and is not related to the number of test users your project can have before its been verified.

Comment: thank you for the answer. My app is verified and has gone through the security assessment. It displays "Verified" on the Oauth consent screen page.

Can you point me to a page where you found that the cap only applies to the unverified apps?

Comment: When a user logs in are you seeing  that the app is verified? are you sure your using the right client id.

Comment: I may have miscommunicated a bit. The app has been in production for a long time and has thousands of users. The user cap had probably been exhausted before I verified the app in the first place. I works fine with the current scopes but right now I am trying to request additional scopes and I need to show the OAuth flow works with the new scopes. I request unverified scopes from a user in the user cap but right now I blocked from doing so. I could not come up with any other solution besides maybe increasing the user cap.

Comment: Okay let me see if i am following you.   I have capped your 100 test users.   Your app has been verified for a while now and is working fine.   You wish to include a new scope and must show google the new scope working.  However due to the fact that you have previously capped your 100 test users you can not test this new scope.    Please verify that I am understanding you correctly if so sounds like a bug and i can contact the team for you.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my situation, thank you

Comment: Okay let me see if i cant get you some more info.

Comment: Okay the owner of the project should be able to run the app and authorize it again. There is no way to remove the 100 test users.  Just make sure one of the owners removes the authorization grant in their google account and it should pop up and request authorization.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I actually tried authorising with the admin account and still got the authorisation error. You said that it's not possible to remove the test users, can you, please, verify that there's is way of increasing that quota?

Comment: There is no way to increase the quota. Have the admin user go to their google account and revoke third party access of the app.   Then they should be able to authorize it again.